# windows service in c++

Tags: c++, windows-services

I want to make an application in c++ which will run periodically. much like an windows service. Is it possible to create a windows service in C++. If yes how?

Any tutorial for this?

EDIT: How can I create an installer for the Windows service?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As indicated in another answer, you need to create a normal C++ program (starting with `main`), and call `StartServiceCtrlDispatcher` Win32 API to tell Windows that you want to run this program as a service. Some information on [this function can be found in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686324%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Additionally, you'll need a mechanism to **install** your service so that it appears in Windows Service Control Panel. And of course, an **uninstall** feature should also be provided. Typically, all the three functions (i.e., install, uninstall and run) are handled in a single executable. The difference in these three is indicated via command line parameters.

You've not indicated what version of VC++ you are using. If you are going with managed .NET code, then it's quite easy as Windows Service template is prebuilt into Visual Studio.

However, if you are going with VC++ 6 (or 100% unmanaged code), then you need to know a lot of low level details. Further choices depend on your know-how of ATL or MFC (if you are going with older versions of the compiler/ runtime).

This might be a good tutorial on [creating Windows Services using C++](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/cservicehelper.aspx).

Comment: These are some good articles on this.            1.http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms685967%28VS.85%29.aspx  2.devx.com/cplus/Article/9857/1954

Comment: how can i create installer for the windows service?

Comment: @syd, that depends on what installer you want to use. If you are going with the bare minimum then command line installation of an individual service is very easy.

Answer (score 2):

C++ is compatible enough with C that the traditional approaches work. You build the application as a normal C++ program (starting with `main`); in the startup you call `StartServiceCtrlDispatcher` to inform the OS that your program can run as a service. Windows doesn't care that you use classes internally.

Answer (score 1):

Check out POCO C++ libraries that allow you to write daemons/services with little effort.

http://pocoproject.org/docs/00100-GuidedTour.html

http://pocoproject.org/slides/190-Applications.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Of course it's possible. Not only possible, but that's what the native API is designed for (well, C really, but close enough).

See Jeff Richter's book "Programming Server side Applications for Windows 2000"

Answer (score 0):

maybe I am late, but I write C++ class for windows services creating and want share code
you need inherit your class from my base class cWinService
http://sprogram.com.ua/en/articles/how-write-service-for-windows-with-cpp

please contact with me if you have any observation.
I am not C++ wizard I am  just study ;)